# Star rating in React for a card component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display a star rating based on the rating number in an object. I want to display 5 grey stars and then display the rating number of coloured stars

This is my component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './card.scss';
import { AiFillStar } from 'react-icons/ai';

const Card = () => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
    const cardData = [
        {
            imgUrl:
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479502806991-251c94be6b15?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80',
            beds: 3,
            baths: 2,
            title: 'Modern apartment in city center',
            price: 390000,
            formattedPrice: '£3,900.00',
            reviewCount: 69,
            rating: 4,
        },
        {
            imgUrl:
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1445019980597-93fa8acb246c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80',
            beds: 1,
            baths: 2,
            title: 'Desert get away in the sun',
            price: 230000,
            formattedPrice: '£2,300.00',
            reviewCount: 108,
            rating: 3,
        },
        {
            imgUrl:
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553653924-39b70295f8da?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80',
            beds: 2,
            baths: 1,
            title: 'Coastal apartment with communal pool',
            price: 900,
            formattedPrice: '£900.00',
            reviewCount: 2567,
            rating: 5,
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className='cardContainer'>
            {cardData.map((card) => (
                <div className='card'>
                    <img src={card.imgUrl} />
                    <div className='cardInner'>
                        <div className='cardInfoTop deemphasise'>
                            {card.beds} beds &bull; {card.baths} baths
                        </div>

                        <h4>{card.title}</h4>

                        <div className='cardInfoMiddle'>
                            {card.formattedPrice}{' '}
                            <span className='deemphasise'>/ pcm</span>
                        </div>

                        <div className='cardInfoBottom emphasise'>
                            {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
                                const ratingValue = i + 1;
                                return (
                                    <AiFillStar
                                        color={
                                            ratingValue > rating
                                                ? 'teal'
                                                : 'grey'
                                        }
                                    />
                                );
                            })}{' '}
                            <span className='deemphasise ml-2'>
                                based on {card.reviewCount.toLocaleString()}{' '}
                                reviews
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

Because of the following: `color={ratingValue > rating ? 'teal': 'grey'}` I am always getting 5 coloured stars. Which is great, but I am struggling to figure out how to reproduce the `card.rating` figure as the coloured stars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small typo + mixed up colours is why you're getting 5!

`rating` is undefined as it's `card.rating`, so the condition always returns `teal`.

If you want it so show the rating as teal (eg rating of 4 is 4 teal stars and 1 grey) you need to swap them around as well

```
<AiFillStar color={ratingValue > card.rating ? "grey" : "teal"} />
                                   ^card.             ^ swap grey/teal
```